# How to build and run a docker container of a mobile flutter app on a physical device on my host machine windows 10 or run it on an android emulator?

Tags: android, flutter, docker, docker-compose, windows-10

I looked for a solution online, they all mention that adb and kvm variables in docker-compose.yml does not work on windows 10 and MacOs but no one seems to provide a solution for someone with windows 10 as a host machine.
A little bit of context here: I have a mobile app I created with flutter, spring boot boot as a backend and mysql as a db.
I want to dockerize all of it to make it available for anyone from any device. I already dockerized spring boot and mysql and tested them.
Now I'm stuck with the flutter mobile part. The service "app" in docker-compose.yml is the flutter mobile. How can I achieve what I mentioned above ?
I want to dockerize the flutter mobile app and run it on an android emulator container or a mobile physical device and I prefer the latter while having a windows 10 as a host machine, I installed wsl2 and I have ubuntu as a distribution.
Here is my docker-compose.yml file below :

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mysqlservice:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysqldb
    networks:
      - quizgameapp-mysqldb
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.24/data

  springboot:
    depends_on:
      - mysqlservice
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: quizgameapp
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    networks:
      - quizgameapp-mysqldb

  app:
    depends_on:
      - springboot
      - emulator
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - FLUTTER_ADB_HOST=emulator # change the value to "emulator"
    volumes:
      - ./:./app
  emulator:
    image: us-docker.pkg.dev/android-emulator-268719/images/30-google-x64:30.1.2
    expose:
      - 8554/tcp
      - 5555/tcp
    ports:
      - "8554:8554/tcp"
      - "5555:5555/tcp"
    volumes:
      - /path/to/Pixel2.avd:/android-home/Pixel2.avd

volumes:
  db-data:

networks:
  quizgameapp-mysqldb:
```

now here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
ENV JAVA_VERSION="8"
ENV ANDROID_TOOLS_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-7583922_latest.zip"
ENV ANDROID_VERSION="29.0.0"
ENV ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION="30.0.3"
ENV ANDROID_ARCHITECTURE="x86_64"
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/local/android-sdk"
ENV FLUTTER_CHANNEL="stable"
ENV FLUTTER_VERSION="2.10.3"
ENV GRADLE_VERSION="7.0.2"
ENV GRADLE_USER_HOME="/opt/gradle"
ENV GRADLE_URL="https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip"
ENV FLUTTER_URL="https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/$FLUTTER_CHANNEL/linux/flutter_linux_$FLUTTER_VERSION-$FLUTTER_CHANNEL.tar.xz"
ENV FLUTTER_ROOT="/opt/flutter"
ENV PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platforms:$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin:$GRADLE_USER_HOME/bin:$PATH"

# Install the necessary dependencies.
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    openjdk-$JAVA_VERSION-jdk \
    curl \
    unzip \
    sed \
    git \
    bash \
    xz-utils \
    libglvnd0 \
    ssh \
    xauth \
    x11-xserver-utils \
    libpulse0 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}

# Install Gradle.
RUN curl -L $GRADLE_URL -o gradle-$GRADLE_VERSION-bin.zip \
  && apt-get install -y unzip \
  && unzip gradle-$GRADLE_VERSION-bin.zip \
  && mv gradle-$GRADLE_VERSION $GRADLE_USER_HOME \
  && rm gradle-$GRADLE_VERSION-bin.zip

# Install the Android SDK.
RUN mkdir /root/.android \
  && touch /root/.android/repositories.cfg \
  && mkdir -p $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT \
  && curl -o android_tools.zip $ANDROID_TOOLS_URL \
  && unzip -qq -d "$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" android_tools.zip \
  && rm android_tools.zip \
  && mv $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/latest \
  && mkdir -p $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools \
  && mv $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/latest $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest \
  && yes "y" | sdkmanager "build-tools;$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION" \
  && yes "y" | sdkmanager "platforms;android-$ANDROID_VERSION" "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64" "emulator" \
  && apt-get install -y libxext6 libxrender1 libxtst6 \
  && yes "y" | sdkmanager "platform-tools"

# Install Flutter.
RUN curl -o flutter.tar.xz $FLUTTER_URL \
  && mkdir -p $FLUTTER_ROOT \
  && tar xf flutter.tar.xz -C /opt/ \
  && rm flutter.tar.xz \
  && git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/flutter \
  && flutter config --no-analytics \
  && flutter precache \
  && yes "y" | flutter doctor --android-licenses \
  && flutter doctor \
  && flutter update-packages

# Configure the Flutter environment variables.
RUN echo 'export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$
```

and this is a script named run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Connect to the Android emulator container.
winpty docker exec -it emulator adb connect emulator:5555

#List the available Flutter devices. You should see the connected dockerized emulator.
flutter devices

# Install the Flutter packages.
flutter pub get

# Run the Flutter app on the connected emulator.
# Add `--trace-startup` to stop the Flutter process from blocking the terminal.
flutter run --trace-startup

mkdir -p 'screenshots' || exit 1

# Take a screenshot of the Flutter app.
winpty docker exec -it emulator adb shell screencap /sdcard/screenshot.png

winpty docker cp emulator:/sdcard/screenshot.png screenshots/flutter-screen.png
```

on my Docker Desktop once I run the command: `docker-compose up emulator`
I get these errors:

```
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.037|   0.036) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.037|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.037|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.037|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.037|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.038|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.038|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.038|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.038|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.038|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.038|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.038|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed 



 to acquire high-priority scheduling: Input/output error
        quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.087|   0.000) W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/root/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
    quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.087|   0.000) W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authentication key '/root/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
    quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.087|   0.000) W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/root/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
    quizgameapp-emulator-1  | pulse: (   0.087|   0.000) W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authentication key '/root/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
tail: cannot open '/tmp/android-unknown/goldfish_rtc_0' for reading: No such file or directoryquizgameapp-emulator-1  | * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
```

the emulator container starts then exits immediately and these are the logs of trying to run this command: `docker compose run app run.sh`

```
=> ERROR [3/6] RUN curl -L https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.0-bin.zip -o gradle-7.0.0-bin.zi  9.0s
------
 > [3/6] RUN curl -L https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.0-bin.zip -o gradle-7.0.0-bin.zip   && apt-get install -y unzip   && unzip gradle-7.0.0-bin.zip   && mv gradle-7.0.0 /opt/gradle   && rm gradle-7.0.0-bin.zip:
#0 4.194   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
#0 4.194                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   305    0   305    0     0    209      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--   309
#0 5.794 Reading package lists...
#0 7.431 Building dependency tree...
#0 7.720 Reading state information...
#0 8.108 unzip is already the newest version (6.0-25ubuntu1.1).
#0 8.108 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
#0 8.113   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
#0 8.113   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
#0 8.113   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
#0 8.113   the last disk(s) of this archive.
#0 8.113 unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of gradle-7.0.0-bin.zip or
#0 8.113         gradle-7.0.0-bin.zip.zip, and cannot find gradle-7.0.0-bin.zip.ZIP, period.
#0 8.113 Archive:  gradle-7.0.0-bin.zip
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c curl -L $GRADLE_URL -o gradle-$GRADLE_VERSION-bin.zip   && apt-get install -y unzip   && unzip gradle-$GRADLE_VERSION-bin.zip   && mv gradle-$GRADLE_VERSION $GRADLE_USER_HOME   && rm gradle-$GRADLE_VERSION-bin.zip]: exit code: 9
```

Every tutorial I found just skips windows 10 and macos as a host machine.
Anyone who can help please ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to run a mobile app within docker? Why don't you simply offer the apk file as a download or put it in an app store to let people install it like usual?

Comment: I had the same question, it's an assignment

Comment: The only solution I could imagine is that you're supposed to run the web version of your flutter app in docker, not the android version. Because there's no way (AFAIK at least) to run a docker container on an Android device. (And again, why would you if you could just as easily install the apk)

Comment: I can't be wrong about this, if I was asked to create a docker image of the web version I wouldn't be asking in first place. The assignment is to run the flutter mobile version on docker and make it run on mobile device or in worst case scenario on android emulator container, the host machine is the one posing alot of troubles here

Comment: Hi @Houssem, were you able to find any solution?